# A spin-1/2 particle A undergoes the decay $A \to B + C + D $, where it is known that B and C are also spin-1/2 particles

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

The complete set of allowed values of the spin of  the particle D is?
Now the answer that I am getting is:

> 'Spin of the left side and combined spin of the products must be same to conserve the spin angular momentum conservation law. '

But it doesn't made sense to me.

Comment: So what in the argument "does not make sense"

Comment: There should be at least one half-integer spin ?

Answer (score 0):

*D* must have half-integral spin, but you know little about anything else.

The simplest case is if all orbital angular momenta involved are zero,
in which case, *D* must have spin 1/2 or 3/2.

Start from the right hand side. That is, $1/2\otimes 1/2 = 1\oplus 0$ for *B*'s spin added to *C*'s. In this case, $0\otimes 1/2= 1/2$; and $1\otimes 1/2 = 3/2\oplus 1/2$,  or $1\otimes 3/2 = 5/2\oplus 3/2\oplus 1/2$. In all cases, there is a spin 1/2, and *A*, included in the right hand sides:  your left hand side.

If non vanishing orbital angular momenta are involved, all bets are off.
Is this your conclusion?